# Webpart access denied for contribute access member

Tags: web-part

Hi am having a strange issue I am working on SharePoint 2010 and I have two document libraries where the permissions of inheritance is broken and permissions given direct;y with a group called "ABC" which has contribute access. I have added users to that group. But the users are not able to see the document library web part i have added to  the site they get the below error 
"Webpart error: Access denied. You don not have permission to perform this action or access this resource". Some one can help me out. thanks

Comment: i think you have given access to the people only for a document library and not to the site where the webpart is added . right ?

Comment: HI Manish I have created this ABC permission group on site and I am using this permission group on the document library web part.

Comment: the users are in other groups of site as well. But i am having issue with some users in this web part library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given audience targeting to the group in the web part and it worked.